# Why paste0() is not working properly inside expression() in either ggplot2 or baseplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, expression

If I want to use `paste0` inside `expression` to label the x-axis, it's not working as intended. But `paste` works.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    x = expression(paste0("It's","mpg")^("paste0 is not working")),
    y = expression(paste("It's ", "disp")^("paste is working")), # had to give extra space
  )
```

[image: ggplot with wrong behavior of paste0]

**Please Note that**

- I have used `paste0` in **x-axis**, which is not showing as intended
- used paste in **y-axis** which is working, but had to give extra space   to separate `It's` and `disp`, which should be the default behavior of `paste` (AFAIK). But that default behavior is not working inside the `expression`.

Also same happens with base-plot

```r
plot(mtcars$disp ~ mtcars$mpg, 
     xlab = expression(paste0("mpg")^("paste0 is not working")),
     ylab = expression(paste("disp")^("paste is working"))
     )
```

[image: base plot with wrong behavior of paste0]

Can anyone please break this out for me,

- why `paste0` is not working?
- and also why `paste`s default behavior is not preserved here??

What's going on here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can only use the operations listed in `?plotmath`.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

`paste` is there, but `paste0` is not.
Also, the function features are not equivalent to the R's functions of the same name.

Comment: Oh, and is there any reason, why we need to use extra space inside of the `paste` (which should be the default behaviour)?!

Comment: It is just the `paste` in the expression is defined differently. There is no `sep` option either. I would consider it as a different language.